# Sift comparison, calculate similarity score, python

Tags: python, comparison, sift

I need to get the similarity score of two images, I'm using the SIFT Comparison, I've followed the tutorial [Feature Matching](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_matcher/py_matcher.html/) but It's missing the score calculation.
You'll find below the code That I used for the sift comparison :

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img1 = cv2.imread('C:/Users/Akhou/Desktop/ALTRAN Tech.jpg',0)          # queryImage
img2 = cv2.imread('rect.png',0) # trainImage

# Initiate SIFT detector
sift=cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()

# find the keypoints and descriptors with SIFT
kp1, des1 = sift.detectAndCompute(img1,None)
kp2, des2 = sift.detectAndCompute(img2,None)

# FLANN parameters
FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE = 0
index_params = dict(algorithm = FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE, trees = 5)
search_params = dict(checks=50)   # or pass empty dictionary

flann = cv2.FlannBasedMatcher(index_params,search_params)

matches = flann.knnMatch(des1,des2,k=2)

# Need to draw only good matches, so create a mask
matchesMask = [[0,0] for i in range(len(matches))]

# ratio test as per Lowe's paper
for i,(m,n) in enumerate(matches):
    if m.distance < 0.7*n.distance:
        matchesMask[i]=[1,0]

draw_params = dict(matchColor = (0,255,0),
                   singlePointColor = (255,0,0),
                   matchesMask = matchesMask,
                   flags = 0)

img3 = cv2.drawMatchesKnn(img1,kp1,img2,kp2,matches,None,**draw_params)

plt.imshow(img3,),plt.show()
```

and I also found a part of a code that calculates the score:

```
# Apply ratio test
good = []
for m,n in matches:
    if m.distance < 0.75*n.distance:
        good.append([m])
        a=len(good)
        print(a)
        percent=(a*100)/kp1
        print("{} % similarity".format(percent))
        if percent >= 75.00:
            print('Match Found')
            break;
```

but when I add it to the comparison code I get this error :

```
  percent=(a*100)/kp1
  TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'list
```

Thank you

Comment: You are dividing `(a*100)` with kp1, where `kp1` is `list` and not a valid numerical value.

Comment: I see, Thank you, I've changed it to `percent=(a*100)/len(kp1)` it's working but I believe it doesn't make sense!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe I found a solution for my problem, for those whom are facing the same trouble, you'll find below the code, I've tested and it seemed to work fine.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename

filename1 = askopenfilename(filetypes=[("image","*.png")]) # queryImage
filename2 = askopenfilename(filetypes=[("image","*.png")]) # trainImage

img1=cv2.imread(filename1,4)
img2=cv2.imread(filename2,4)

# Initiate SURF detector
surf=cv2.xfeatures2d.SURF_create()

# find the keypoints and descriptors with SURF
kp1, des1 = surf.detectAndCompute(img1,None)
kp2, des2 = surf.detectAndCompute(img2,None)

# BFMatcher with default params
bf = cv2.BFMatcher()
matches = bf.knnMatch(des1,des2, k=2)

# Apply ratio test
good = []
for m,n in matches:
    if m.distance < 0.75*n.distance:
        good.append([m])
        a=len(good)
        percent=(a*100)/len(kp2)
        print("{} % similarity".format(percent))
        if percent >= 75.00:
            print('Match Found')
        if percent < 75.00:
            print('Match not Found')

img3 = cv2.drawMatchesKnn(img1,kp1,img2,kp2,good,None,flags=2)
plt.imshow(img3),plt.show()
```

If you want to work with sift, you can just change the `surf=cv2.xfeatures2d.SURF_create()` to `sift=cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()` and `kp, des = sift.detectAndCompute(img,None)`

Thank you

Comment: the indentation is wrong,,, a=len(good) and the next lines must execute after the loop